# Session being set but session data not being passed

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a session issue. for some reason, the session is being set, but the session data is not being passed. I check the session path and that's all correct. Below there's a login handler and then the session checks once a user is logged in.

I var_dumped the session and got nothing, but var_dumped the session_id() on both scripts and got the same session id, indicating that the session is being made, but for some reason not being passed.

Thanks for any help.

login_handler.php

```
<?php 
session_name("tradesman");
session_start();
include '../includes/con.inc.php'; 


$errors = 0;
$email_address = $_POST['tradesman_email'];
$password = $_POST['tradesman_password'];
$remember_me = $_POST['tradesman_remember_me'];



    $login_check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tradesman WHERE email_address = :email_address");

    $login_check->bindParam(':email_address', $email_address);

    $login_check->execute();


    if($login_check->rowCount() === 1){


    }else{
       $response["message"] = 'denied';
       $errors++;       
    }

if($login_check->rowCount() === 1){

    while($row = $login_check->fetch()) { 

            $db_password = $row['password'];
            $tradesman_id = $row['tradesman_id'];
            $trade_name = $row['trade_name'];
            $email_address = $row['email_address'];


        if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {


            $update_key = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tradesman SET token=:token WHERE tradesman_id=:tradesman_id");

                 $update_key->bindParam(':token', $token);
                 $update_key->bindParam(':tradesman_id', $tradesman_id);


            if($update_key->execute()){

            $token = sha1(microtime()); 
            $_SESSION['trade_name'] = $row['trade_name']; 
            $_SESSION['tradesman_id'] = $row['tradesman_id'];
            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;

            $response["message"] = 'tradesman_login_success';
            }else{
            $response["message"] = 'denied';
            $errors++;
            }



        } else {

           $response["message"] = 'denied';
           $errors++;   

        }
    }   
}


echo json_encode($response); 
exit();

?>
```

account.php - after login (session check only)

```
<?php 
session_name("tradesman");
session_start();

 print_r($_SESSION['token']);
 print_r($_SESSION['tradesman_id']);
 print_r($_SESSION['trade_name']);

require_once 'includes/con.inc.php'; 

$session_key = $_SESSION['token'];

$check_user = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tradesman WHERE token =:session_key LIMIT 1"); 

$check_user->bindParam(':session_key', $session_key, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($check_user->execute()) {
       $check_user->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

      if($check_user->execute()){

        if($check_user->rowCount() === 1){


     while($row = $check_user->fetch()) {

        $tradesman_id = $row['tradesman_id'];

      }

        }else{

          header('Location:index.php');
          exit();

        }

      }else{
          header('Location:index.php');
          exit();
      }
?>
```

Comment: _“but var_dumped the session_id() and got the session id”_ - where - in _both_ scripts? And they session id was the same in both cases? Did you check via browser dev tools, whether the cookie was accepted, and whether it gets send back with the next request?

Comment: @bob see what error reporting shows and PDO error handling https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @CBroe I've updated the question. and yes in both scripts and they were both the same and the cookies were accepted.

Comment: @bob Do you realize that you have put `session_name("tradesman");
session_start();` in that order in `login_handler.php `? Also you don't have to use  `while($row = $check_user->fetch())` just go with `$row = $check_user->fetch(); $tradesman_id = $row['tradesman_id'];`

Comment: @Toleo That is the way it should be (the `session_name()` part).

Comment: @jeroen oh, `session_name()` i took it quickly thinking it was `$_SESSION` for a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your first script:

```
        ...
        $update_key = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tradesman SET token=:token WHERE tradesman_id=:tradesman_id");

        // Here you bind the $token variable to the placeholder
        $update_key->bindParam(':token', $token);
        $update_key->bindParam(':tradesman_id', $tradesman_id);

        // Here you execute the query, $token is not defined yet
        if($update_key->execute()){

            // Here you set the token, it will not be available in the database
            $token = sha1(microtime()); 
            $_SESSION['trade_name'] = $row['trade_name']; 
            $_SESSION['tradesman_id'] = $row['tradesman_id'];
            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
            ...
```

You set the token in the database before you define it so you are setting an empty value in your database.

First define the token, then store it in the database and the session.

As you are binding parameters, moving it to before the `if` statement should do it:

```
...
$token = sha1(microtime()); 
if($update_key->execute()){
    ...
```

Comment: I checked before the token, is being saved to the db. I moved it to the suggested location, but unfortunately no change.

Comment: @bob How can something that is not defined be saved correctly to the database, that makes no sense. Are you posting your actual code?

Comment: I know right. Yes, this is the actual code. it's really strange.

Comment: You were correct. I forgot I was adding a token into the db in the sign-up handler. Sorry for wasting your time, my ineptitude is the culprit. Thank you very much for spotting it though.

Comment: @bob Glad you got it sorted out :-)